# How to pass attributes between classes (a cloning issue)

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn

I have the following code that works fine as it is:

```
class Classifiers(object):
    """Multiple classifiers"""

    class SVM():
        """
        SVM Classifier Object.
        This is binary classifier
        """
        @staticmethod
        def classifier(X, y):
            from sklearn import svm
            classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
            return(X,y,classifier)


class FeatureSelection(object):
    def select_RFECV(self, X, y, clf):
        """
        Feature ranking with recursive feature elimination 
        and cross-validated
        """
        from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
        from sklearn.svm import SVC
        estimator = SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True)


        # Below retrieving Clf failed
        #estimator = clf

        # Code below is ok
        selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
        selector = selector.fit(X, y)
        print selector.support_
        return


def main():
    # call estimator
    svm = Classifiers.SVM()

    # Create dataset
    from sklearn import datasets
    X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples = 100, n_features =20, n_classes=2)

    # Feature selection 
    FS = FeatureSelection()
    sel = FS.select_RFECV(X,y,svm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It produces output like this:

```
[False  True False False False  True False False False False  True  True
 False False  True False False False False  True]
```

However my problem is this. The attribute `select_RFECV` in class `FeatureSelection()`,
takes one of its input the estimator `clf`. Now, this `estimator` is actually identical with `svm = Classifiers.SVM()`.

When I commented out `estimator = SVC(kernel="linear", probability=True)` and uncomment `estimator = clf`. I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object '<__main__.SVM instance at 0x1112f0fc8>' (type <type 'instance'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator a it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

How can I correctly pass the attributes among classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

First one:

```
svm = Classifiers.SVM()
```

Judging from your code, svm is just an empty instance now, with no members. Just like doing `svm = object()`. Since `classifier` is a static method (and I would not judge that decision, just take it as an input) - and the only method - there's no need to instansiate the class. This line is not needed.

Second one:

```
sel = FS.select_RFECV(X,y,svm)
```

This method expected X, y and a clf. It get's X, y, and an empty instance. What this method should receive, and that's a guess, is:

```
sel = FS.select_RFECV(*Classifiers.SVM.classifier(X,y))
```

This would pass the output of the classifier method `(X, y, classifier)`, as the input of the method.

The cloning errors you're receiving has nothing to do with your classes, but rather with the fact that sklearn expects a classifier and receives something else.